# Regex "is not a constant" compilation error

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to write a regex in Go to verify that a string only has alphanumerics, periods, and underscores. However, I'm running into an error that I haven't seen before and have been unsuccessful at Googling.

Here's the regex:

```
pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+`)
```

Here is the error:

```
const initializer regexp.MustCompile("^[A-Za-z0-9_\\.]+") is not a constant
```

What does "not a constant" mean and how do I fix this?

Comment: `const` in Go is like `constexpr` in C++, if you know it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This happens when you're trying to assign to a constant that has a type that can't be constant (like for example, `Regexp`). Only basic types likes `int`, `string`, etc. can be constant. See [here](https://blog.golang.org/constants) for more details.

Example:

```
pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+`)
// which translates to:
const pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+`)
```

You have to declare it as a `var` for it to work:

```
var pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+`)
```

In addition, I usually put a note to say that the variable is treated as a constant:

```
var /* const */ pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+`)
```

Answer (score 11):

The error is pretty clear. If you are trying to do this globally...

Don't do:

```
const pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+`)
```

Instead do:

```
var pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+`)
```

Or if you really want the pattern in a constant:

```
const pattern = `^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+`
var alphaNum = regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
```

Answer (score 6):

In Go declaration context, assignment with a simple `=` creates a constant, not a variable. (Outside of a declaration, it's an assignment to a variable that must already exist.)

But a constant initialization has to include only constants - not calls like `regexp.MustCompile()` - so `pattern` *can't* be a constant in this case, even if you don't plan on changing its value later. (In fact, even if you could somehow initialize it without calling anything, a `Regexp` can't be a constant in Go; only basic types can be.)

That means you need to make it a variable by either putting it inside a `var` statement or declaring it inside a function with `:=` instead of `=`:

```
var (
   pattern = ...
)
```

or

```
var pattern = ...
```

or

```
func something() {
   pattern := ...
}
```