# declare constants in golang using os.Getenv results in 'const initializer in os.Getenv("MY_SECRET") is not a constant'

Tags: go, environment-variables, constants

If I declare constants as the following I get the error 'const initializer in os.Getenv("MY_SECRET") is not a constant'. Why is this?

New to Go and I see the return type of Getenv is a string, but I don't understand why this wouldn't work as a constant.

```
const (
    secret     = os.Getenv("MY_SECRET")
    key        = os.Getenv("MY_KEY")
)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just like the error says, a [constant must have a constant value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants). You cannot set it to the return of a function. It *must* be evaluated at compile time (e.g. a string literal). If you want to store the values of environment variables looked up at run time, you'll have to store them in variables, not constants.

Comment: Simple enough, figured it had something to do with compile time.  Thank you. Not sure why people are down voting a legitimate question that I didn't see asked before on S.O.

Comment: There is some prior art, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976076/